# How to get the Object URL in AWS S3 using Amplify from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin

In my Android Project using Kotlin, I am uploading an image to AWS S3 using Amplify. The  file is uploaded with **transferUtility**

```
val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
            .context(applicationContext)
            .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
            .s3Client(AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance()))
            .build()

    val file = File("path_to/file")
    val key = "public/propic/" + user.id+".jpg"
    val uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload(key,file)

uploadObserver.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {

        override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState) {
            if (TransferState.COMPLETED === state) {
                Toast.makeText(this@UploadActivity, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
}
```

The file is being perfectly uploaded to AWS S3. I need to get Object URL of the uploaded file once it has been uploaded. So that I can use the Object URL to load image view from the S3.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question, the URL of an object in an S3 Bucket is

```
 https://BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file
```

Note that to access it in this way, the object must be publicly available.